# Every time i scan NFC new activity created

Tags: android, nfc

few weeks ago i already ask this question but 'till know there's no answer.
i don't know what wrong, but every time i scan nfc tag, the same new activity always created.
how do i solve this?
here the code

```
public class CheckinActivity extends Activity{  
private boolean mResumed = false;
private boolean mWriteMode = false;
NfcAdapter mNfcAdapter;
PendingIntent mNfcPendingIntent;
IntentFilter[] mWriteTagFilters;
IntentFilter[] mNdefExchangeFilters;                    

TabelToko toko;          
TabelAbsen helper;
Cursor model=null;
AlmagAdapter adapter=null;
ListView list;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    TextView viewId = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.idlogin);
    DigitalClock jam = (DigitalClock)findViewById(R.id.jam);
    viewId.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    jam.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);                                            
    mNfcPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
    toko = new TabelToko(this);            
    toko.insertToko();

    getWaktu();
    helper = new TabelAbsen(this);        
    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listChek);                          
    model=helper.getAll(tanggal);
    startManagingCursor(model);
    adapter=new AlmagAdapter(model);       
    list.setAdapter(adapter);        
}            
@Override
public void onDestroy() {   super.onDestroy();       helper.close(); }
private void cekNfc (String id) throws SQLException, UnsupportedEncodingException, GeneralSecurityException{                
    toko.open();        
    Cursor c = toko.CekToko(id);        
    if (c.moveToFirst()){
        getWaktu();
        Cursor d = helper.cekAbsen(id, tanggal);                            
        if (d.moveToFirst()==false){
            //insert checkin
            helper.insertAbsen(NFCSalesAttendanceActivity.idpegawai, NFCSalesAttendanceActivity.username, 
                id, c.getString(1), c.getString(2), tanggal, jam, "checkin");                                           
            model.requery();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Checkin", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{                       
            if (d.getCount()==1){
                helper.insertAbsen(NFCSalesAttendanceActivity.idpegawai, NFCSalesAttendanceActivity.username, 
                        id, c.getString(1), c.getString(2), tanggal, jam, "checkout");                  
                    model.requery();
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Insert Checkout", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else{   
                d.moveToFirst(); d.moveToNext();            
                helper.updateAbsen(NFCSalesAttendanceActivity.idpegawai, NFCSalesAttendanceActivity.username, 
                    id, c.getString(1), c.getString(2), tanggal, jam, "checkout",d.getString(0));                   
                model.requery();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Update Checkout", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }  
        }                   
    }
    else{
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Perhatian!").setMessage("NFC Tidak Terdaftar di Database!")
        .setNeutralButton("Tutup", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {                  
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { } }).show();
    }
    toko.close();             
}


@Override    
protected void onResume() {    
    super.onResume();
    mResumed = true;               
    // Sticky notes received from Android
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {            
        NdefMessage[] messages = getNdefMessages(getIntent());
        byte[] payload = messages[0].getRecords()[0].getPayload();            
        try                                     { 
        cekNfc(new String(payload)); }
        catch (SQLException e)                  { e.printStackTrace(); } 
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)      {  e.printStackTrace(); }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)  { e.printStackTrace(); } 
        catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }                                   
        setIntent(new Intent()); // Consume this intent.
    }
    enableNdefExchangeMode();        
}   
private void enableNdefExchangeMode() { mNfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, mNfcPendingIntent, mNdefExchangeFilters, null); }      

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) { // NDEF exchange mode               
    if (!mWriteMode && NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        NdefMessage[] msgs = getNdefMessages(intent);            
        byte[] payload = msgs[0].getRecords()[0].getPayload();                                                     
    }
}   
NdefMessage[] getNdefMessages(Intent intent) {  // Parse the intent             
    NdefMessage[] msgs = null;        
    String action = intent.getAction();
    //jika ada action
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action) || NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {                      
        Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
        if (rawMsgs != null) {
            msgs = new NdefMessage[rawMsgs.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < rawMsgs.length; i++) {  msgs[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[i]; }
        }
    } 
    return msgs;
}

class AlmagAdapter extends CursorAdapter { AlmagAdapter(Cursor c) { super(CheckinActivity.this, c); }       
    @Override
    public void bindView(View row, Context ctxt, Cursor c) {            
        AlmagHolder holder=(AlmagHolder)row.getTag();           
        holder.populateFrom(c, helper);         
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context ctxt, Cursor c, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
        View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.checkin, parent, false);
        AlmagHolder holder=new AlmagHolder(row);            
        row.setTag(holder);         
        return(row);
    }
}
static class AlmagHolder {
    private TextView nama=null;
    private TextView alamat=null;
    private TextView waktu=null;
    private ImageView gambar=null;
    private View row=null;

    AlmagHolder(View row) {
        this.row=row;                   
        nama=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.namatoko);
        alamat=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.alamat);
        waktu=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.waktu);
        gambar=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.gambar);
    }

    void populateFrom(Cursor c, TabelAbsen helper) {            
        nama.setText(helper.getNamaToko(c));
        alamat.setText(helper.getAlamatToko(c));
        waktu.setText(helper.getWaktu(c));
        if (helper.getStatusCheckin(c).equals("checkin"))       { gambar.setImageResource(R.drawable.kanan); }
        else if (helper.getStatusCheckin(c).equals("checkout")) { gambar.setImageResource(R.drawable.kiri); }           
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered the same probleme recently,( it seems that you can't prevent your Application from calling onDestroy, everytime you touch a NFC-Tag.)->Edit...

So you have to save everything in [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) or any other [Stroage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

In onCreate you can Reload your Data, so even a new Activity will get all needed Information.

Edit:

After some Time of Testing, the SingleTask did work for me. I put everything that had to be reinitialized into the onStart() Method.

Additional I put the Logic from onResume() to onNewIntent() where I catch the Intent directly.

But I still save everything for future use :D.

Answer (score 1):

try to set the launchMode to singleTop

and override onNewIntent()

Comment: here the screen shoot. this is the main app http://i.imgur.com/ubCQw.png and this the activity that alway appears everytime i scan nfc http://i.imgur.com/iBXcs.png

Answer (score 0):

Set the launch mode of the Activity to "singleTask" in the manifest. That should solve the issue, as now there cannot be more than one instance of the Activity.

Comment: From the screenshots you posted, I see that you are using a TabActivity. So the Activity code you posted above, that is setting the ForegroundDispatch is running inside a TabWidget. I have not previously encountered this situation before. Could you try adding the ForegroundDispatch to the TabActivty instead and in its onNewIntent() forwarding the Intent to your CheckinActivity?

Comment: it not working, maybe another idea? thanks anyway, this problem really annoy me.